# Chef running git clone results in host key verification error

Tags: capistrano, chef-infra, ssh-keys

I am using Chef, invoked by Capistrano.

There is a directive to clone a repository using git.

```
git node['rails']['rails_root'] do
  repository "git@myrepo.com:/myproj.git"
  reference "master"
  action :sync
  user node['rails']['rails_user']
  group node['rails']['rails_group']
end
```

When it gets to this point, I get:

```
 ** [out :: 10.1.1.1] STDERR: Host key verification failed.
```

So, I need to add a "known_hosts" entry. No problem. But to which user? The core of my problem is that I have no idea which user is executing what commands, and if they are invoking sudo, etc.

I've run keyscan to populate the known_hosts of root, and the user I ssh in as, to no avail.

Note, this git repo is read-protected, and requires ssh key access.

Comment: The git repository will be cloned as user `node['rails']['rails_user']` or am I wrong? I assume that users known_hosts is the one in question.

Comment: Based on http://docs.opscode.com/resource_git.html, user=The system user that is responsible for the checked-out code. That user appears to work when I update their known_hosts. Can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The git repository will be cloned as user `node['rails']['rails_user']` (via https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html) - I assume that users known_hosts file is the one you have to modify.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to solve https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ssh_known_hosts

this worked for me

Comment: If I read it right, the documentation says it won't work with chef-solo. Is this correct? I didn't list that in my question, but it is a factor for me.

Comment: I use it with vagrant(which is chef solo) so I guess It works just fine

Comment: Chef solo doesn't use data bags so that is probably what the documentation means by 'doesn't work with Chef solo'.  there are features listed where you can put the Host keys in data bags and it handles it automatically.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an ssh wrapper approach.  Look [here](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_deploy.html) for details.

Briefly do the following steps

First, create a file in the cookbooks/COOKBOOK_NAME/files/default directory that is named wrap-ssh4git.sh and which contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/bin/env ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $1 $2
```

Then, use the following block for your deployment:

```
directory "/tmp/private_code/.ssh" do
  owner "ubuntu"
  recursive true
end

cookbook_file "/tmp/private_code/wrap-ssh4git.sh" do
  source "wrap-ssh4git.sh"
  owner "ubuntu"
  mode 00700
end

deploy "private_repo" do
  repo "git@github.com:acctname/private-repo.git"
  user "ubuntu"
  deploy_to "/tmp/private_code"
  action :deploy
  ssh_wrapper "/tmp/private_code/wrap-ssh4git.sh"
end
```

Comment: I am trying this method but keep getting this error: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.  Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue as below

```
_home_dir = nil
node['etc']['passwd'].each do |user, data|
    if user.eql? node['jenkins']['username']
        _home_dir = data['dir']
    end
end
key_config ="Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n"
file "#{_home_dir}/.ssh/config" do
    owner node['jenkins']['username']
    group node['jenkins']['username']
    mode "0600"
    content key_config
end
```